GliNER finetuning - no validation loss is logging
I am trying to fine-tune using this notebook: GLiNER/examples/finetune.ipynb at main · urchade/GLiNER (github.com)
However, the logs only show 'loss' , which I assume is the training data set loss, but there is no recorded validation set loss
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="models",
    learning_rate=5e-6,
    weight_decay=0.01,
    others_lr=1e-5,
    others_weight_decay=0.01,
    lr_scheduler_type='linear', #"cosine",
    warmup_ratio=0.1,
    per_device_train_batch_size=5,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=5,
    num_train_epochs=2,
    eval_strategy="epoch",
    save_steps = 100,
    save_total_limit=10,
    dataloader_num_workers = 1,
    use_cpu = True,
    disable_tqdm=False,
    logging_dir='logs',
    logging_steps=10,
    eval_steps=10,
    do_train=True,
    do_eval=True,
    seed=7,
    )

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    tokenizer=model.data_processor.transformer_tokenizer,
    data_collator=data_collator)

Where is validation loss computed?? I want to log both the training and validation sets' loss

This is the configuration I'm using (wandb as logger is the only change), and I have both training and validation loss logged :
TrainingArguments(
eval_strategy="steps",
save_strategy="steps",
save_total_limit=10,
report_to="wandb",
)
Version : gliner==0.2.10
